# content deliveries and public links missing in npsp org

Tags: npsp, contentdocumentlink, content-delivery, contentdistribution, file-sharing

I have created a trigger on contentDocumentLink in my developer org and generating public url for file sharing using ContentDistribution object and when i started moving code to npsp org sandbox, ContentDistribution is invalid object type and i also searched "content deliveries and public links" in setup but nothing found.
Does anyone know the solution of this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I think content delivery is not activated in the org as mentioned in the [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000240244&type=1) link .